# missing FROM-clause entry for table "g"

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select distinct "BillingCountry", count(g."Name") as genre_occurance from 
        (select "BillingCountry", g."Name" as sub2 from "Invoice" 
        join "InvoiceLine" as invl on invl."InvoiceId" = "Invoice"."InvoiceId" 
        join "Track" as t on t."TrackId" = invl."TrackId" 
        join "Genre" as g on g."GenreId" = t."GenreId" 
        where "BillingCountry" in ('USA', 'Canada', 'Brazil', 'France', 'Germany')
        group by "Invoice"."BillingCountry", g."Name") as sub1
```

I know there have been many solutions for errors like this, but I have tried following those solutions but i couldn't get the query to work, I just don't understand the solutions, i need help on this.

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "g"
LINE 1: select distinct "BillingCountry", count(g."Name") as genre_o...
```

Comment: You're trying to `count(g."Name")` in your outer query, but there is no table called `g` in the outer query.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: the `distinct` in combination with a `group by` is pretty much useless.

Comment: It's just hard to tell what the query should look like since you are not telling what it's supposed to do. What do you want to count *exactly*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of the column `g.Name` is the subquery, so it is not *visible* in the outer query.
Also, in the subquery `g.Name` is aliased as `sub2`, so this alias you should use in the outer query.

But, in the subquery you `group by Invoice.BillingCountry, g.Name` without doing any aggregation. Why?

The result of the subquery is all the distinct combinations of `BillingCountry` and `g.Name`, which you could also get by using `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`:

```
select distinct BillingCountry, g.Name as sub2 
from Invoice 
join InvoiceLine as invl on invl.InvoiceId = Invoice.InvoiceId 
join Track as t on t.TrackId = invl.TrackId 
join Genre as g on g.GenreId = t.GenreId 
where BillingCountry in ('USA', 'Canada', 'Brazil', 'France', 'Germany')
```

Finally in the outer query, you use aggregation without a `GROUP BY` clause.

Maybe you want to aggregate in the outer query, something like this:

```
select BillingCountry, count(Name) as genre_occurance 
from (
  select i.BillingCountry, g.Name 
  from Invoice i 
  join InvoiceLine as invl on invl.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId 
  join Track as t on t.TrackId = invl.TrackId 
  join Genre as g on g.GenreId = t.GenreId 
  where i.BillingCountry in ('USA', 'Canada', 'Brazil', 'France', 'Germany')
) as t
group by BillingCountry
```

which can be written without a subquery:

```
select i.BillingCountry, count(g.Name) as genre_occurance 
from Invoice i 
join InvoiceLine as invl on invl.InvoiceId = i.InvoiceId 
join Track as t on t.TrackId = invl.TrackId 
join Genre as g on g.GenreId = t.GenreId 
where i.BillingCountry in ('USA', 'Canada', 'Brazil', 'France', 'Germany')
group by i.BillingCountry
```

Answer (score 0):

you have aliased g.name to sub2  in the inner query, so the outer select doesn't know "name" column and also outer query doesn't know whats inside the inner query, rather what you return in select.
you can fix your query like so:

```
select distinct "BillingCountry", count(sub2) as genre_occurance 
from  (
            select "BillingCountry", g."Name" as sub2 
            from "Invoice" 
            join "InvoiceLine" as invl on invl."InvoiceId" = "Invoice"."InvoiceId" 
            join "Track" as t on t."TrackId" = invl."TrackId" 
            join "Genre" as g on g."GenreId" = t."GenreId" 
            where "BillingCountry" in ('USA', 'Canada', 'Brazil', 'France', 'Germany')
            group by "Invoice"."BillingCountry", g."Name"
        ) as sub1
```